# Transforming an SQL table

Tags: sql, django

I am trying to write a nice SQL query, but I am failing. I am trying to create a select statement that returns the following:

```
Date     | Cash | Checking | Savings
--------------------------------------
May 2017 | 30   |   300    |  3000
Apr 2017 | 40   |   400    |  4000
```

My tables are like this:

```
Balances
* id
* date
* amount
* item_id

BalanceItems
* id
* name
```

So the column names (cash, checking and savings for example) are stored in BalanceItems. Basically I don't know how I can get the name from BalanceItems in the column header.

---

I am building this in Django, so ideas of how to elegantly do this there are also appreciated. These are the models:

```
class Balances(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey('BalanceItems', related_name='balances_balance_items')
    date = models.DateField()
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)

class BalanceItems(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I might be able to use `pivot` to get my desired result but that command doesn't exist in sqlite. I don't want to use `case` statements because the amount of columns can change.
So I have ended up accepting that this one view is going to do a whole bunch of database calls and use Python to keep everything organized.

Answer (score 0):

If we know the expected values, we can use a [pivot](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```sql
select [date], [Cash], [Checking], [Savings]
from 
(
    select [date]
    , amount
    , name
    from Balances b
    inner join BalanceItems bi
    on bi.id = b.item_id
) source
pivot 
(
    sum(amount)
    for name in ([Cash], [Checking], [Savings])
) pvt
order by [date]
```

Otherwise we need [dynamic sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql); though the solution's otherwise the same as the one above:

```sql
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
select @sql = coalesce(@sql + ', ', '') + quotename(name)
from @BalanceItems
set @sql = '
    select [date], ' + @sql + '
    from 
    (
        select [date]
        , amount
        , name
        from Balances b
        inner join BalanceItems bi
        on bi.id = b.item_id
    ) source
    pivot 
    (
        sum(amount)
        for name in (' + @sql + ')
    ) pvt
    order by [date]
'
exec (@sql)
```

Comment: Ah, I see that my question is ambiguous. I edited it. I have the two sql tables. I am trying to make a select statement that returns the first table as the result.